# Show 4Tab of 12Tab random and Hide another tab

Tags: css, random, tabs, hide, show

I need a code for show tabs exmapls:
i use 12tabs
and now need just show 4tab random show on my page and hide another tab for user
example
tab1
tab2
...
tab12

i need show random this tabs
tab1
tab8
tab11
tab4
and hide another tab

Comment: What do you mean by tab? Could you please give code sample?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is handling it on back-end. Just make 4 elements( tab or anything else)on front-end, then from back-end, use randoms functions or if you use PHP Array you can use shuffle() function and directly pass 4 first indexes to your front-end in that 4 specific elements. 
Hope it help